# Nodejs HAPI request getting called twice from browser

Tags: node.js, rest, hapi.js

I am a newbie to Node and am trying to host a restful service using [hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/), my code is as follows:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{id}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        console.log('request check');
        var user = userservice.get(encodeURIComponent(request.params.id));
        reply('Hello ', user.name);
    }
});
```

However as I see in the log request check is getting logged twice.
Is there something missing or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for any help.
- Vaibhav

Comment: Does `reply('Hello ', user.name);` also get called twice? Can you show us where you invoke this route on your client side?

Comment: I am just calling it through chrome browser like http://localhost:3000/myapp/32

Comment: When i am invoking this through the browser i am getting this problem, by default the browser is GET, however through postman its working as expected.

Comment: Do you get the 'Hello' message or not? Also, what happens if you browse to `http://localhost:3000/32` instead?

Comment: i got the Hello message in both the cases

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Chrome console shows 2 request being fired by default and that could just be the reason for it. not sure why thats happening though.

- Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

this is most probably the automatic request to `/favicon.ico` the browser does when accessing a website.
try to log the request path `console.log(request.info.path);`

either you change your request path to `path: '/user/{id}'` or skip `/favicon.ico` requests.